# Error while restoring Couchbase database using cbrestore command in mac

Tags: macos, couchbase

I am getting the below error while restoring the couchbase database to my local mac from a server.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/python/cbrestore", line 
12, in <module>
pump_transfer.exit_handler(pump_transfer.Restore().main(sys.argv))
File "/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/python/pump_transfer.py", line 80, in main
rv = pumpStation.run()
File "/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/python/pump.py", line 136, in run
rv = self.transfer_bucket_msgs(source_bucket, source_map, sink_map)
File "/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/python/pump.py", line 233, in transfer_bucket_msgs
source_map)
File "/Applications/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/python/pump_bfd.py", line 546, in total_msgs
rv, db, ver = connect_db(x, opts, CBB_VERSION)
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Emraan

Comment: Could you please add the full command you are using?

Comment: @Mathew Groves ./cbrestore -x rehash=1 /Users/abc/Documents/couchbaseback23102018 http://localhost:8091 -u Administrator -p abc --bucket-source=RP --bucket-destination=RP

Comment: I had faced the same issue with couchbase 6 on windows 10. Tried everything but nothing helped. Finally, I restarted the couchbase service and tried and restore was successful.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you solved it?